# AWS Service Only Returning XML

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

I'm using AWS KMS through REST + presigned urls and can't seem to get it to return anything but XML. I'd really prefer JSON. My URL looks something like:

```
kms.<host>/Action=ListAliases<Authentication Params>
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the HTTP `Accept` header in your request to `application/json` or maybe `text/json`.